# Struts + Back Button

Tags: struts2

My MVC is Struts 2

My requirement is to clear some error message in the leading page AFTER the back button is clicked in the browser.

The sequence is:
Page A --> Page B --> Page C

The Page B can be navigated from Page A or from Page C (by clicking the back button). If Page B has an error message, and back button from Page C is clicked, this error message has to be removed. But I have no way of determining how the user navigated to Page B (considering there are 2 ways as mentioned above).

Searched everywhere for a solution. Found out that window.history is not a reliable way to parse the previous page.

Also, the window.location is not changing because of the Struts 2 quirks with tiles.

The frustrating thing is browser back button does not hit the server. Neither does it process JSP or struts tag. Luckily, though, it runs the javascript.

So I came up with a custom solution that uses server and client timestamps. It seems to work in all browsers.

I would like to know if there is an easier way.

```
 <%

            if (session.getAttribute("myTime") != null) {
                //server sends the time in millis on the first invocation
                Long tmStamp = Long.parseLong((String) session.getAttribute("myTime"));
                // out.println(tmStamp);
                 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                 Date javaDt = new Date();
                 javaDt.setTime(tmStamp);
                // out.println(" " +  sdf.format(javaDt));
                 Date clientDt = new Date();
                 Long clientMillis = clientDt.getTime();
                 Long timeDiff = clientMillis -tmStamp;
         %>
                <script>
                var currDt = new Date().getTime();
                var dt = new Date(<%= tmStamp%>);
                dt.setTime(<%=tmStamp%>);
                var jsDt = new Date();
                jsDt.setTime(currDt);
                //alert( "<%= tmStamp %>" + " javascript time=" + (currDt - dt.getTime()) + ' timeDiff=' + (1 * <%= timeDiff%>) + " " +  jsDt  + " " + dt);
                //we expect the server to repond within 5 seconds
                if (currDt  > (<%= tmStamp %> + (1*<%= timeDiff %>) +  5*1000)) {
                    //alert("referer is summary" )
                    clearError();
                } else {
                    //alert("referer is not summary");
                 <s:if test="flag == 'none'">
                    $('<tr><td align="center"> <font color="red" style="font-size:14px;font-family:"sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica";height:20px;width:180px; font-weight:bold;" ><blink>No Result found for the given Search Criteria</blink></font></td></tr>')
                        .insertAfter("#lastRow");
                    $('<tr><td align="center"> <font style="font-size:14px;font-family:"sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica";height:20px;width:180px; font-weight:bold;" ><blink>No Result found for the given Search Criteria</blink></font></td></tr>')
                    .insertBefore("#firstRow");
                </s:if>
                }
                </script>
        <% } else {
            out.println("No session attribute for myTime");
        }
        %>
```

Comment: What? Which error messages?

Comment: As shown in the code a "blink" tag is added when the property "flag" is none. The requirement is to remove this when the user clicks back button. It is not important to know the error messages. Basically, I want to modify DOM upon clicking the back button. Thx

Comment: Edited the query with an illustration. Thx

Comment: How do you get to C page if B have an error?

Comment: User visits Page A and navigates to Page B without any errors. Then changes some options and submits a form resulting in error. Still on Page B. Then again changes some options and goes to Page C. Now the DOM of Page B will have the error messages. A back button click takes the user to Page B still showing error. We don't know if (s)he arrived at Page B from Page A or Page C (Note: a back click from Page C should clear the error by requirement). The important thing is how to figure out the previous location when the URL is the same as current one per windows history. Hope this clarifies. Thx